# How to integrate contract first webservice into Grails using CXF?

Tags: web-services, grails, cxf

Hi there i am looking for a working example on how to integrate and use **contract first** webservices using Grails and Apache CXF.

I found http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=85983334 but this example does not seem to work anymore.

The question is not related to a client but the actual implementation of the webservice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the cxf client plugin:

https://github.com/ctoestreich/cxf-client

Here is their demo app:

https://github.com/ctoestreich/cxf-client-demo

Comment: I guess that I was not clear in my question.. I need to implement/provide the webservice based on a wsdl and not create the client. But anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Grails cxf plugin : http://grails.org/plugin/cxf

Comment: CXF plugin adds the needed dependencies but does not help me to do contract first webservices. The plugin promotes code first.

Comment: Did you try plain spring-ws? http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html